# after installing oh-my-zsh on mac git branch don't show, but after .oh-my-zsh it works

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

macos BigSur
installed oh-my-zsh by sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

when I start terminal git branch don't show but after run .oh-my-zsh in shows.

How to do this automatically as earlier?

I uninstalled it, reinstalled it - nothing, the same problem

.zshrc:

```
export ZSH="/Users/*****/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: oh-my-zsh is just a set of configuration files for `zsh`. Installing it copies the files to your machine; sourcing `.oh-my-zsh` is how you tell `zsh` to *use* those files. Put the source command in your `.zshrc`.

Comment: but it is yet in .zshrc :
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
doesnt help

Comment: I suggest that you post the relevant part of your ~/.zshrc in your question.

Comment: @user1934428 i did

Comment: BTW, it would be easier to read, if (when posting the code here) you would remove all the irrelevant comment lines and just focus on the statements.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have the [git-promot](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git-prompt) plugin loaded.

You only have the [git](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git) plugin loaded. Which provides nice shortcuts but no prompt info.
You need to edit the `plugins` values array to include it.

Find `plugins=(git)` in your above .zshrc file and replace it with.

```bash
plugins=(
  git
  git-prompt
)
```

It is worth noting that changes are not immediate after you make them, you will need to re`source` the `.zshrc` file by either starting a new terminal or running `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: thanx

I added plugins=(... git-prompt), and nothing happened

how I have to install this plugin?

Comment: @zubescu: In this case, maybe a screenshot would indeed help. Post a screenshot of your terminal session, where you do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`, followed by a `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me that experienced a `"command not found"` on your terminal after install Oh my Zsh.

NOTE:
When you installed Oh my Zsh, The oh my zsh installer make a backup of orignal `~/.zsh` file (that contains all of your export data) to `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`.

I am assuming `code` is your default editor. Else, you can use `nano`

1. Run `code ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` to open your backedup zshrc file.
2. Copy all exports on this file `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` and exit
3. Paste the copied data into the new `~/.zhrc` file just after the `# User configuration` line. ([See ~/.zhrc file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqjcf.png))
4. Close and reopen your terminal and all paths will be ok